How to perform fast row selection by row index
I have a loop that involves many complex operations, and it is slow. Basically, the pseudo code for it is like this.
set.seed(123)

n_rows <- 100000
n_cols <- 20000

# large memery require
dt1 <- as.data.table(matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows))

dt2 <- as.data.table(matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows))

dt3 <- as.data.table(matrix(runif(n_rows * n_cols), nrow = n_rows))

dim(dt1)

# run on first 100 rows here
sapply(1:100, function(x) {
    # just a toy run
    cat("x =", x, "\n")
    a1 <- dt1[x, ]
    a2 <- dt2[x, ]
    a3 <- dt3[x, ]
    # Do someting here, just a toy run
    x1 <- a1 + a2 + a3
    x2 <- sum(x1) + sum(a1[x > 0])
    x3 <- x2 + sum(a2[x > 0])
    return(x3)
})


dt1, dt2, dt3 have same dimensions here.
It is very slow, so I run profvis to find time-consuming steps.
library(profvis)
profvis({
    sapply(1:100, function(x) {
    # just a toy run
    cat("x =", x, "\n")
    a1 <- dt1[x ,]
    a2 <- dt2[x, ]
    a3 <- dt3[x, ]
    # Do someting here, just a toy run!!!
    x1 <- a1 + a2 + a3
    x2 <- sum(x1) + sum(a1[x > 0])
    x3 <- x2 + sum(a2[x > 0])
    return(x3)
    }) 
})

It seems that selecting rows using data.table is taking a significant amount of time.
In real data, this section requires extracting the same row from three different tables and performing complex operations on it, including calculating probability distributions, determining thresholds, filtering data, scoring, etc. So, I use a loop here, The code has been simplified here for brevity.
I have tried:

using data.table

From: Fast way to select rows within table in R?

Looping over rows is always going to be slow compared to some kind of vectorised operation. Reconceptualising this so you're not looping over rows and doing one-by-one selections, but rather combining/summing whole objects all at once is how you'd speed this up.

What is the idea of x>0 that does not make sense. xis a number between 1 and 100. It is definitely greater than 0. So what is its purpose? Also a1 and a2 are each data.tables with 1 row. The why would you want to subswt them again with a1[x>0] this will still yield a1

in real data, this section requires extracting the same row from three different tables and performing complex operations on it, including calculating probability distributions, determining thresholds, filtering data, scoring, etc.  So, I use a loop here, The code has been simplified here for brevity.

My point is that the core of your issue probably isn't a couple of milliseconds selecting a row from a data.table. Doing a complex operation a (potentially massive) nrow(...) times will pretty much always be slow unless you can find a clever way of allowing your code to run in chunks, or in parallel, instead of piecemeal. Maybe a tiny improvement could be made by joining dt1/2/3 together first and then only selecting 1 row instead of 3 selections? Or use the by=1:nrow(dt) in data.table to maybe take advantage of its multi-core abilities?

Not sure why you using an sapply here. Calculating with the subsets directly instead of extracting the rows first is much faster.
> library(data.table); library(tictoc)
> tic()
> x <- 1:100
> a1 <- dt1[x, ]
> a2 <- dt2[x, ]
> a3 <- dt3[x, ]
> x1 <- a1 + a2 + a3
> x2 <- rowSums(x1) + rowSums(a1[x > 0])
> x3 <- x2 + rowSums(a2[x > 0])
> toc()
3.974 sec elapsed
> x3 |> head()
[1] 50004.52 50037.75 50078.40 49971.06 49918.73 49957.64


Its just a toy run, in real data, this section requires extracting the same row from three different tables and performing complex operations on it, including calculating probability distributions, determining thresholds, filtering data, scoring, etc. The code has been simplified here for brevity.

@zhang That's what I thought. The key message is, calculate with the subsets directly. In particular, note, that I used rowSums, which can calculate with the subsets and runing in C. Use/write functions that outsource operations to faster languages. Consider Rcpp, matrixStats packages, exploit more the data.table functionalities. Also check if you really have enough RAM since one dt* is using about 15 GB. Good luck!
